# Disproportionate windows in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: windows-10, sql-management-studio

Some windows are of a disproportionate size in SQL SSMS and I need to reset them. They're so big that many of the text boxes overlap each other and practically make it unusable. I have recently replaced my old development laptop with a new one and I did a fresh install of Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise. When I initially installed management studio, my laptop's screen resolution was set at 2880x1620 with "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" set to 200%. I've now docked my laptop and adjusted the built-in display to 1920x1080 and 100% and when I start management studio the dialog windows are huge!

This seems like a problem with Windows rather than SSMS.  Any advice on how to fix this would be helpful.

I don't have enough rep to post images, so here are the links to them:

The new database dialog: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiG7X.jpg

The login window: [http://imgur.com/Zm7hOa9](https://imgur.com/Zm7hOa9)

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide.